# is there a difference between [Serializable] and [Serializable()] in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I've bumped into examples using either of both notations. I can't find anything about it what tells which one is the common one, why 2 notations are allowed, and if there is actually any subtle difference between the two.

anyone an idea?

Comment: Good question.. always wondered it myself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Nope, no functional difference.

Why the 2 different styles, you ask? The first notation is allowed for brevity. The 2nd notation is allowed because some attributes take parameters:

```
[Category("Foobar related methods.")]
public void Foo()
{
}
```

Also note that [Serializable] is really just short-hand for [SerializableAttribute()] - C# lets you omit the Attribute suffix as well as the empty constructor parens.

Answer (score 12):

No, there is no difference. `[Serializable]` is just syntactic sugar for `[Serializable()]` because the C# syntax lets you miss out the constructor brackets if there is a default attribute constructor.

Note that both are really syntactic sugar for `[SerializableAttribute()]` as attribute declarations also let you miss the Attribute suffix.

Comment: I googled "[Serializable()] vs [Serializable]". BOOM! Got my answer, which has been waiting for my question for over a decade.   I love it.

Answer (score 6):

both uses the default c'tor, there is no difference at all.