# What are the differences between [Serializable] and [Serializable()]

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a difference between [Serializable] and [Serializable()] in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770643/is-there-a-difference-between-serializable-and-serializable-in-c)

I always use `[Serializable()]` in my WebServices, before a class declaration, to serialize it. Today in a tutorial I see `[Serializable]`...

What are the differences?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing.

If you had needed to pass parameters, you would have need the first syntax, though.

Comment: @Tigran: Added a bit more because I'm sure I was going to get downvotes from lots of people who don't like short answers, even though it probably wasn't necessary. xD

Answer (score 0):

There is any functional difference actually. 
The allowed 2 different types cause several arguments can have a parameters, so its tru also in this case:

can have a look on this answer: [is there a difference between [Serializable] and [Serializable()] in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770643/is-there-a-difference-between-serializable-and-serializable-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between them since the constructor of SerializableAttribute accepts no parameters.
On the otherhand, if any attribute constructor accepts parameters, they should be written inside ().